# Normalize multiple values using values of one factor in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

We have some tidy data with treatments (multiple samples and control), time points, and measured values. I want to normalize all the samples by dividing by the corresponding time point in the control variable.

I know how I would do this with each value in its own column, but can't figure out how to us a combination of `gather` `mutate`, `sumamrise` etc from `tidyr` or `dplyr` to do this in a straightforward way.

Here is a sample data frame definition:

```
structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
value = c(10, 20, 15, 100, 210, 180, 110, 180, 140), 
as.factor.treat. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
.Label = c("c", "t1", "t2"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = c("time", "value", "treat"), 
row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data frame looks like this:

```
time value   treat
   1    10      c
   2    20      c
   3    15      c
   1   100     t1
   2   210     t1
   3   180     t1
   1   110     t2
   2   180     t2
   3   140     t2
```

Expected output. same but with `normvalue` column containing `c(1,1,1,10,10.5,12,11,9,9.333333)`

I'd like to get out columns of normalized `value` for each treatment and time point using tidyverse procedures...

Comment: It might be useful to see what the expected output should be.

Comment: Like, do you just want to divide t1 and t2 at timepoint 1 by 10 (the value of the c group at timepoint 1), etc.?

Comment: @Atticus29 updated with clearer input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group by `time` (assuming that, as in the example, it is the grouping variable for time-point) then we can use bracket notation in a `mutate` statement to search only within the group. We can use that to access the control value for each group and then divide the un-normalized value by that:

```r
df %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    mutate(value.norm = value / value[treat == 'c'])

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   time [3]
   time value treat value.norm
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1     1    10 c           1   
2     2    20 c           1   
3     3    15 c           1   
4     1   100 t1         10   
5     2   210 t1         10.5 
6     3   180 t1         12   
7     1   110 t2         11   
8     2   180 t2          9   
9     3   140 t2          9.33
```

All this does is take the value column of each row and divide it by the value for the control sample with the same time value. As you can see, it doesn't care if sample `t1` is missing an observation for `time == 1`:

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                     value = c(10, 20, 15, 210, 180, 110, 180, 140), 
                     as.factor.treat. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                                                  .Label = c("c", "t1", "t2"), class = "factor")), 
                .Names = c("time", "value", "treat"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    mutate(value.norm = value / value[treat == 'c'])

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   time [3]
   time value treat value.norm
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1     1    10 c           1   
2     2    20 c           1   
3     3    15 c           1   
4     2   210 t1         10.5 
5     3   180 t1         12   
6     1   110 t2         11   
7     2   180 t2          9   
8     3   140 t2          9.33
```

Comment: That is great! I edited my input data frame so I'm going to edit your answer to match `treat` instead of `as.factor.treat`... Thanks.

Comment: This relies on the treatments being even multiples of the controls? What if `t1` was missing a time point can it function sort of like an SQL `where t1.time == c.time`? <-- testing: looks like it does!

Comment: Yeah, it just takes every row that exists and divides it by the value for the control at that timepoint. As long as you have a value for the `control` treatment for each timepoint you won't run into problems.